# NHibernate mapping a separate Lib

Tags: nhibernate, mapping

My `Route` has `Stops`, in my db there are no relationships (FK), just a `RouteId` in the Stop table. So I've added a `IList<Stop> Stops` in my Route class.
Now my classes (Route and Stop) are in a Lib (separate project).
I have a Console app where I define the mapping and test things out.
How should I define my mappings and where (`*.nhm.xml` | `App.config`). I know that it has to do with adding assembly and namespace but I just can't find how.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the `hbm.xml` can be in another assembly, you have to specify the assembly qualified name in the mappings

example:

```
<class name="the.name.space.User, Assemblyname" table="USER">
```

Comment: My hbm.xml files are listed under Mapping folder (see img). Can you please tell me what should I add to these files (example)?